# Windows XP Map drive failed

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, file-sharing

Greetings,

I have a Windows Web Server 2008 VPS and two client machines.  One is a Windows 7 box and the other XP.

I configured one folder as a share on the 2008 box and attempted to mount it on each of the clients.

The catch is it won't work with XP.  Same username/password but I get Access granted on the Win 7 but for XP I get:

Failure Reason:  Unknown user name or bad password.
 Status:   0xc000006d

Any ideas?

If this duplicates any other question please refer me but I cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you map it by IP address rather than computer name?

i.e.,

`\\192.168.0.1\sharename\`

instead of

`\\myserver.mydomain.local\sharename\`

Do you have an Active Directory domain set up?  If so, make sure the DNS on the Windows XP client points to a DNS server/DC that has a record for your Win2008 VPS.   Otherwise, verify the Windows XP and Windows 7 point to the same DNS servers and the same order.

If this all appears to be correct, try unjoining and rejoining the XP computer from/to the domain.

Comment: Currently I am just accessing it by the Ip address directly.  Maybe I should access it via a domain instead?

Comment: Are any of the machines currently joined to a domain?  Are they all on the same IP subnet?  If there's currently no domain, make sure all 3 computers are set to the same workgroup name.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers - what it ended up being in my problem was NTLM v2 is the only accepted Auth method and XP will not negotiate to v2 unless forced.  Thanks to all who made suggestions